# Trying to get the difference of range sliderInput in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm working through an [R Shiny tutorial](https://mastering-shiny.org/basic-ui.html), and decided to veer off the path, but I'm lost at the moment. A previous exercise had me create a range slider, and I checked the docs to fancy it up with arguments. Now what I'm trying to do is create a textOutput below it to show the value of the difference between the min and max.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("rang", "Range", value = c(100, 2000), min = 0, max = 15000, 
              sep = ",", pre = "$", ticks = FALSE, dragRange = TRUE,
              width = "600px"),
  textOutput(costDiff())
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  costDiff <- reactive({
    costDiff <- input$rang[2] - input$rang[1]
  }) 
  
  output$costDiff <- renderText("$",{
    costDiff()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I'm receiving:

`Error in costDiff() : could not find function "costDiff"`

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    sliderInput("rang", "Range", value = c(100, 2000), min = 0, max = 15000, 
                sep = ",", pre = "$", ticks = FALSE, dragRange = TRUE,
                width = "600px"),
    textOutput('costDiff')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    costDiff <- reactive({
        input$rang[2] - input$rang[1]
    }) 
    
    output$costDiff <- renderText({
        paste('$', costDiff())
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you! So if I'm understanding right, costDiff can only be called as a function inside of the server, and in the UI, it would referenced by name?

Comment: Yes, reactive values are called like a function inside a reactive context, what do i mean by that? Simply call it inside `observe`, `reactive`, or `render` functions. Inside the ui, 'costDiff' refers to output$costDiff, they are two different things.  In this case you named the output the same as the reactive, that's what caused the confussion.